# How to pull url file extension out of url string using javascript

Tags: javascript, file, url

How do I find the file extension of a URL using javascript? 
example URL:

```
http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/include/marquee/design.swf?width=792&height=294
```

I just want the 'swf' of the entire URL.
I need it to find the extension if the url was also in the following format

```
http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/include/marquee/design.swf
```

Obviously this URL does not have the parameters behind it.

Anybody know?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get exactly what I needed thanks to Alex. I slightly modified it to; fileExtension("http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/include/marquee/design.swf?width=792&height=294"); function fileExtension(url){fileSplit = url.split('?')[0]; fileIndex = fileSplit.substr(fileSplit.lastIndexOf(".")+1); alert(fileIndex); }; works like a charm

Answer (score 62):

```
function get_url_extension( url ) {
    return url.split(/[#?]/)[0].split('.').pop().trim();
}
```

## example:

```
get_url_extension('https://example.com/folder/file.jpg');
get_url_extension('https://example.com/fold.er/fil.e.jpg?param.eter#hash=12.345');
```

outputs ------> `jpg`

Comment: Some modification to check for querystring `return match.indexOf('?') !== -1
      ? match.substr(0, match.indexOf('?'))
      : match;`

Comment: What does the # do?

Comment: @tnyN it's just adding # as another identifier to potentially split the url on. # is used in hash routing. Angular uses a version of hash routing, and React Router also has hash routing capabilities. I don't think the regex is exhaustive to all cases, but certainly covers the question. To only check for a query string would just be `/[?]/`

Comment: This doesn't work if the URL doesn't have an extension

Answer (score 26):

Something like this maybe?

```
var fileName = 'http://localhost/assets/images/main.jpg';

var extension = fileName.split('.').pop(); 

console.log(extension, extension === 'jpg');
```

The result you see in the console is.

```
jpg true
```

if for some reason you have a url like this `something.jpg?name=blah` or `something.jpg#blah` then you could do

```
extension = extension.split(/\#|\?/g)[0];
```

drop in

```
var fileExtension = function( url ) {
    return url.split('.').pop().split(/\#|\?/)[0];
}
```

Comment: what about `http:://someurl.com/file.png?user_token=some.hash.with.dot` ?

Answer (score 12):

For the extension you could use this function:

```
function ext(url) {
    // Remove everything to the last slash in URL
    url = url.substr(1 + url.lastIndexOf("/"));

    // Break URL at ? and take first part (file name, extension)
    url = url.split('?')[0];

    // Sometimes URL doesn't have ? but #, so we should aslo do the same for #
    url = url.split('#')[0];

    // Now we have only extension
    return url;
}
```

Or shorter:

```
function ext(url) {
    return (url = url.substr(1 + url.lastIndexOf("/")).split('?')[0]).split('#')[0].substr(url.lastIndexOf("."))
}
```

Examples:

```
ext("design.swf")
ext("/design.swf")
ext("http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/include/marquee/design.swf")
ext("/marquee/design.swf?width=792&height=294")
ext("design.swf?f=aa.bb")
ext("../?design.swf?width=792&height=294&.XXX")
ext("http://www.example.com/some/page.html#fragment1")
ext("http://www.example.com/some/dynamic.php?foo=bar#fragment1")
```

Note:
File extension is provided with dot (`.`) at the beginning. So if `result.charat(0) != "."` there is no extension.

Comment: Should add code to also handle this kind of url `http://www.blabla.com/include/bla.html#hello+hello1`

Comment: This is the best one I've seen thus far but it doesn't pass all 30 of the test on this page: https://projects.jamesandersonjr.com/web/js_projects/grab_file_extension_test.php

Comment: This one returns a whole filename, not just extension.

Answer (score 7):

This is the answer:

```
var extension = path.match(/\.([^\./\?]+)($|\?)/)[1];
```

Comment: To handle a case like "...abcd.jpg#awesome", where "#" is after the extension, use this:

    var ext = path.match(/\.([^\./\?\#]+)($|\?|\#)/)[1];

Answer (score 5):

```
url.split('?')[0].split('.').pop()
```

usually #hash is not part of the url but treated separately

Comment: Nice answer.  It accounts for multiple periods in the URL's file name.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html). Specifically, something like `/([^.]+.[^?])\?/`.

Comment: Specifically, this: `var t = /.+\.([^?]+)(\?|$)/`. Then you can say `url.match(t)`, and you'll get 'swf' in your examples.

Answer (score 4):

```
  // Gets file extension from URL, or return false if there's no extension
  function getExtension(url) {
      // Extension starts after the first dot after the last slash
      var extStart = url.indexOf('.',url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
      if (extStart==-1) return false;
      var ext = url.substr(extStart+1),
          // end of extension must be one of: end-of-string or question-mark or hash-mark
          extEnd = ext.search(/$|[?#]/);
      return ext.substring (0,extEnd);
  }
```

Comment: Tested this against the other functions in the answers (  https://jsbin.com/woguriruhe/edit?js,console ) and found that this one seems to be the most accurate.

Answer (score 4):

This method works fine :

```js
function getUrlExtension(url) {
  try {
    return url.match(/^https?:\/\/.*[\\\/][^\?#]*\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\??#?/)[1]
  } catch (ignored) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the (relatively) new [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) object to help you parse your url. The property [`pathname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/pathname) is especially useful because it returns the url path without the hostname and parameters.

```
let url = new URL('http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/include/marquee/design.swf?width=792&height=294');
// the .pathname method returns the path
url.pathname; // returns "/products/flashplayer/include/marquee/design.swf"
// now get the file name
let filename = url.pathname.split('/').reverse()[0]
// returns "design.swf"
let ext = filename.split('.')[1];
// returns 'swf'
```

Comment: It's not asked in the OP's question, but if the URL contains multiple periods in the file name, then there probably should be a .pop() or .length - 1 included in the code as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
const getUrlFileType = (url: string) => {
  const u = new URL(url)
  const ext = u.pathname.split(".").pop()
  return ext === "/"
    ? undefined
    : ext.toLowerCase()
}
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32238228)

Answer (score 1):

```
    var doc = document.location.toString().substring(document.location.toString().lastIndexOf("/"))
    alert(doc.substring(doc.lastIndexOf(".")))
```

Comment: i agree with @Federico though.. a regex might be better.. i'm just awful at writing them.

Answer (score 0):

```
function ext(url){
    var ext = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1),
        ext = ext.split('?')[0],
        ext = ext.split('#')[0],
        dot = ext.lastIndexOf('.');

    return dot > -1 ? ext.substring(dot + 1) : '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use npm packages, [File-type](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type) is another option.

They have browser support, so you can do this (taken from their docs):

```
const FileType = require('file-type/browser');

const url = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a9/Example.jpg';

(async () => {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const fileType = await FileType.fromStream(response.body);

    console.log(fileType);
    //=> {ext: 'jpg', mime: 'image/jpeg'}
})();
```

It works for gifs too!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I like to imporve [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54692145/6877799), it means my answer will support `#` too:

```js
const extExtractor = (url: string): string =>
  url.split('?')[0].split('#')[0].split('.').pop() || '';
```

This function returns the file extension in any case.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna use this solution. these packages are using latest import/export method.
in case you wanna use const/require bcz your project is using commonJS you should downgrade to older version.

i used
"got": "11.8.5","file-type": "16.5.4",

```
const FileType = require('file-type');
const got = require('got');

const url ='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a9/Example.jpg';
(async () => {
    const stream = got.stream(url);

    console.log(await FileType.fromStream(stream));
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex like this or modify it for your goal.

I hope it will help you because I can't find better solution and make up it.

```js
function getExtensionFromURL(URL){
  const tokens = URL.match(/(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\?|\#|$))/g) 
  if(!tokens[0]) return false 
  return tokens[0].replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\.]/g,'') 
}
console.log(getExtensionFromURL("https://ya.com/sjsjs/text-ee/image.jpeg/target.png?q=tail&w=force"))
// .png
console.log(getExtensionFromURL("https://ya.com/sjsjs/text-ee/image.jpeg/target.png#fff=eee")) 
// .png
console.log(getExtensionFromURL("https://ya.com/sjsjs/text-ee/image.jpeg/target.png"))
// .png
```

[image: Screenshot from regex101]

Answer (score -2):

```
var fileExtension = function( url ) {
    var length=url.split(?,1);
    return length
}
document.write("the url is :"+length);
```